# LCPI.IBProvider not registered on Local Machine

Tags: c#, delphi, exception, firebird, interbase

A legacy program coded in Delphi 7 and accessing an Interbase 3 database using C# was moved from Windows 7 64 Bit to Windows Server 2012 64 Bit.

Now, when we run the program, it triggers the C# code, which accesses the IB 3 database. This  triggers this error: `System.InvalidOperationException: The 'LCPI.IBProvider' provider is not registered on the local machine.`

Looking online, I'm not sure which LCPI.IBProvider to register. (It seems to have already been registered on the Windows 7 machine.)

We are unable to update the Interbase 3 database without jeopardizing our work.

Any thoughts / suggestions?

Comment: Why is it tagged firebird? And seriously, interbase 3 that must be 15-20 years old by now? Also: make sure all components are the same bitness, most likely the application is AnyCPU and therefor running under 64 bit while the registered library is 32 bit only (or the application is 32 bit and the lib is 64 bit).

Comment: It was tagged Firebird because the DB is run on EMS Interbase/Firebird Manager. (Yes, this is legacy software using Interbase 3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please contact the ibprovider support , it might be that you need to register it on that machine

http://www.ibprovider.com/eng/download.html

Comment: We found an old install file in our software repository that had the IBProvider software needed to resolve this issue. Thanks!